# Replacing User_ID in a URL

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've pulled some of this code from [WP Download Manager Download Limit](https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/download/download-limit/), in effort to create a reset link on the frontend (Initially, this is shown on the /wp-admin/users page). However, I can't seem to work out why "data-user='{$user_id}" isn't actually placing the User ID into the URL on the frontend. I need the $user_id to have the current users ID in the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('.wpdm-reset-limit').on('click', function () {
                $(this).html('Reseting...');
                var $this = $(this);
                $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'wpdm_reset_user_download_limit', user: $(this).data('user')}, function () {
                    $this.html('<span style="color: #39bd62"><i class="fa fa-check-double"></i> Done</span>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <a href='#' class='wpdm-reset-limit' data-user='{$user_id}'>Reset</a>
```

**Currently Shown:**

```
<a href='#' class='wpdm-reset-limit' data-user='{$user_id}'>Reset</a>
```

**Ideal Outcome:**

```
<a href="#" class="wpdm-reset-limit" data-user="1234">Reset</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get user id by either AJAX callback or generate the script dynamically. Try:

```
<a href='#' class='wpdm-reset-limit' data-user='{<?php get_current_user_id(); ?>}'>Reset</a>
```

Comment: Hi Mulli, thank you for your input, but the result removes anything after 'data-user'. Here's what I get: <a href="#" class="wpdm-reset-limit" data-user="">Reset</a>

Comment: @MikeSmith Please note that you must be logged in to get an ID, otherwise the function will return empty string. But if you are logged in, there must be a much larger problem.

Comment: I am logged in when trying the suggested method. The code is placed in wp-content/theme/mytheme/content/content-single.php. I don't understand why it's not finding the current users ID though. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I've solved it. I used `<?php echo "<a href='#' class='wpdm-reset-limit' data-user='{$user_id}'>Reset</a>";?>`